# Oracle Coherence Map deserialize error

Tags: java, deserialization, oracle-coherence

I sometimes randomly get an error while deserializing the Aggregator. The error happens inside the `readExternal` method when it tries to deserialize the map. The key value pairs inside the `HashMap` doesn't appear to be null. Has anyone seen a similar issue before? I am using Oracle coherence 3.7. The stack trace suggest the problem happens while reading the map value type from the header.

```
this.calcMap = in.readMap(5, new HashMap<PriceArrayKey, Double>());
```

The writeExternal method code

```
out.writeMap(5, this.calcMap, PriceArrayKey.class, java.lang.Double);
```

stacktrace given below

```
Caused by: Portable(java.io.EOFException)
    at com.tangosol.io.AbstractByteArrayReadBuffer$ByteArrayBufferInput.readPackedInt(AbstractByteArrayReadBuffer.java:443)
    at com.tangosol.io.MultiBufferReadBuffer$MultiBufferInput.readPackedInt(MultiBufferReadBuffer.java:683)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferReader.readAsUniformObject(PofBufferReader.java:3344)
    at com.tangosol.io.pof.PofBufferReader.readMap(PofBufferReader.java:2537)
    at com.xyz.coherence.aggregator.Calculator.readExternal(Calculator.java:428)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing "2" and "5" as different property indexes; that seems like an obvious problem.

I would also suggest looking carefully at the PriceArrayKey serialization, since an error there could cause what you are seeing here.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when i posted the question. The property indexes are same in the code. Interestingly if i change the writeExternal method to this(removing the value type) the problem goes away which seems strange. out.writeMap(5, this.calcMap, PriceArrayKey.class);

Comment: Is it possible that some of the Double values are null? Or something weird, like Double.NaN?

Comment: I tested with NaN and null values it doesn't seem to cause the issue. Anyway the value will never be null since a primitive double is used for the value calculation.As i understand you get an EOFException while reading if it tries to read more bytes than it was actually written which points to some inconsistencies in the way coherence writes it each time.

Comment: Agreed that it appears that there is some difference between the reading and writing of the data. It is always possible that it is in Coherence code, but that is less likely due to the test coverage (and the wide-spread use in thousands of systems). Nonetheless, it is still possible, so I suggest posting the POF serialization logic in the various classes in question.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the implementation of the serializer for `PriceArrayKey`.  If you are using a [PofSerializer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18683/com/tangosol/io/pof/PofSerializer.html) implementation, are you sure that you have called `out.writeRemainder(null)` and `in.readRemainder()` in the serialize and deserialize methods?